# battery maximum capacity is 72%

Tags: mac, battery

I bought Mac M1 air 2020 version in July 2021. It has been almost twi years.

My battery details are as follows

> Health Information: Cycle Count:    216
> Condition:    Service Recommended
> Maximum Capacity: 72%

Is it necessary to change the battery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s advising you of service.  It means your battery is out of performance spec.

Will it harm your Mac?  No.

Will you get degraded performance from your battery?  Yes.

What this means is when you need your Mac the most without being connected to mains, you won’t have the battery life you expect. Should you change it?  It’s entirely up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the detail given in the System preferences.

Mine is showing the same message (MacBook Pro, 2016), but it still runs a couple of hours on a charge depending what I run. Teams is the worst...

As to whether you should replace you have to weigh up the cost and the time you will be without a machine compared to replacement and perhaps selling it on. That is all personal to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. :)